# What is the proper way to display a new view from a view and then returning to it in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a simple app that have 3 views, HomeView, MenuView and GameView.

In the HomeView I have 2 buttons (Menu and Start Game).  When the menu button is clicked,  I open the MenuView using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)displayMenu:(id)sender{
  MenuView *mv = [[MenuView alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubView:[mv view];
  [mv release];
}
```

In the MenuView, I have a button that will allow the user to return to the HomeView.  When this button is clicked,  I use the following code to return to the HomeView

```
- (IBAction)returnToHome:(id)sender{
  HomeView* hv = [[HomeView alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubView:[hv view];
  [hv release];
}
```

The above code is working but is this the correct way of doing it?  I was under the impression that when I call the addSubView, the view will be retain so If keep going back and forth between HomeView and MenuView, will i have multiple instance of HomeView and MenuView retained since I keep calling addSubView from each of the view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `UINavigationController`, which will allow you to push `UIViewControllers` on to the stack.
Using the `UINavigationController` you will get an nice naviagtionbar in at the top of you screen and the back button.

You can find a nice example here:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: is it possible to use UINavigationController but not have the back button in the navigation bar?  The reason why I'm asking this is because when I reach the last view (aka the result view) I do not want them to be able to return to the previous screen.  I want them to only able to return to the HomeView

Comment: it looks like I can set "navigationBarHidden" to YES and it should accomplish what I want to do.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found this way the most useful and convenient. When calling the new view use this:

```
    HomeView* hv = [[HomeView alloc] init];
        (here you can add a uninavigation controller)
    [self presentModalViewController:hv animated:YES];
```

Then to dismiss this view and go back use this:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

@atbebtg:

There is a way to do that, infact there are several, since there not really is a "right way" to do it.

For me this works well:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

This will hide the Navigation Bar, so the user can't go back to the last screen.

The other thing you could do is to create your own subclass of UIViewController and not support the button event, like this:

```
    - (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    //inform the user, that going back is not possible, for example with UIAlertView
    //[self.delegate infoViewDidFinish:self];
}
```

However, this solution seems a bit odd, because the user expects a existing button to work.
Still, this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given answers that present modal view controllers or build a navigation stack. In most cases I would use one of these approaches. Yet, the simplest way to fix the code in the question is to just remove the menu view from the super view. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)returnToHome:(id)sender{
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```